# android, audio filters

Tags: android, audio-recording, microphone

I would like to make audio records (via `MediaRecorder`/`AudioRecorder`) and then play recorded file with some changes (special effects) (e.g. increasing/decreasing speed, adding echo, mix with other predefined audio file, etc)).

Do you have any suggestions how can I do that?

Do you have any interesting examples concerned this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I came across the following Api's which would be useful for you to remix a music piece.
[Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) to change the frequency.
then try using [BassBoost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/BassBoost.html) to change the Bass of the music.Finally , use the [audiofix package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/package-summary.html).I hope this should get you going.

Comment: @garimma: Have you ever implement Bassboost in android? I need help regarding it. I am not able to implement the BassBoost in My Music app.